# AWS S3 bucket to bucket sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I use the following command line to synchronize two buckets:

```
aws s3 sync --delete s3://[SOURCE_BUCKET] s3://[TARGET_BUCKET]
```

I have a Go lambda that performs some validation on the bucket content, and I want this lambda to perform the synchronization. However, I don't find any `Sync()` function in `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3`.

Is there a way to have the same behavior as the command line, or should I re-implement the behavior myself? Seems to be a pretty generic use case, I would be surprised if it didn't exists already.

Comment: You have to re implement it.

Comment: Looks like you will need to do it yourself or use something already existing, like https://github.com/seqsense/s3sync .

Comment: Yes I found this but when looking at the code I saw that "S3 to S3 sync feature is not implemented". I'll do it on my own then